# Imagemagick Annotate Rotate Text Only

Tags: imagemagick

I have the following Imagemagick command line within a larger command line. I am trying to overlay this text on an image. It works fine until I add the `-rotate 90` then it rotates the entire image 90º. I just want to rotate this text 90º and nothing else. I put this line in parentheses but no luck. Any advice would be appreciated

```
" \( -background transparent -fill 'rgba(255,255,255,.3)' -gravity south -rotate -90 -pointsize 70 -font 'High_School_USA_Serif.ttf' \
 -annotate +350+40 '#66789' \) ";
```

Full comment line below (updated/simplified)...

```
"convert -size 1800x1800 xc:'#0080ff' ../trait_assets/clothes/F.A.S.T._Suit.png -composite   
\( ../trait_assets/name_patch.png -font 'High_School_USA_Serif.ttf' -fill white -pointsize 150 -gravity center \    
-draw \"text 0,20 'JACKSON'\" \    -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -resize 210x -gravity south -geometry -94+80 \    
-background 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' -rotate -2 \) -composite    
\( -background transparent -fill 'rgba(255,255,255,.3)'  -gravity south -pointsize 60 -font 'High_School_USA_Serif.ttf' \
 -annotate -70+6 \"#6577\" \)  
temp_images/main.png "
```

[image]

[image]

[image: Image example of annotate position code]

Comment: Please click [edit] and add a proper [mcve] so we can help you. That means an input image, a full command, the current (incorrect) output image and the (correct) output image you actually wanted (or a mockup of it). A black background image is fine `magick -size 640x480 xc:black ...`

Comment: Hi Mark - ok added

Comment: You can rotate your text in -annotate. The arguments are `-annotate XdegreesxYdegrees{+-}tx{+-}ty text`. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#annotate

Comment: Why are you using `convert` that is ancient version 6 syntax. Can you move to v7? If the other images you reference in your command are important, please include them. If not, please remove them. Your example should be **minimal** and **complete**. That means none of the stuff we don't need plus all of the stuff we do need. Working this way helps ensure volunteers, such as Fred (fmw42) and myself, have the bandwidth to help everyone. Thank you.

Comment: @mark I simplified the code example and included the two relevant images. TY! 

Comment: @fmw42 that worked! however `-annotate -10x-10 -70+6 \"#66763\"` now the text that is generated over the image is the `-70+6` positional text, not the `#66763` ?! I need the rotation and the passioning too

Comment: No space allowed in -annotate angle and offset arguments only between that and text. Close it up to `-10x-10-70+6 \"#66763\"`

Comment: @fmw42 - thank you. (I added a new example image in the post). That almost works. However, I can't set the annotated numbers to move to the left. I need them in that blank space to the left but no matter how I change that last number (150) it doesn't move. I can move it vertically, just not horizontally. `-annotate -90x-90+90+150 \"#3556\"`

Comment: Does this work:  `-annotate 270x270+90+150 \"#3556\"`

Comment: Your code is not using the full set of arguments in your code section above. Please post the full code you are using.  Why are you rotating afterwards?

Comment: Please post input and then code exactly for those images, so that I can run your code.

Comment: #fmw42 `-annotate 270x270+90+150 \"#3556\"` that worked! Thank you very much!! If you want to put it as an answer I can accept it

Comment: How am I supposed to deduce that the notation -annotate XdegreesxYdegrees{+-}tx{+-}ty text translates into something concrete in the form -annotate -45x-45+0+0 "TESTING" . Come one guys, that notation is incredible hard to decipher. If the notation is not totally obvious, ALWAYS give a numerical example, also in the manual. I'm talking to you, manual writers for ImageMagick.